# Tridion Cache Delay

Tags: web8.5, cache-channel-service, jms

We have configured JMS ActiveMQ for Tridion Cache Channel Approach.
Once we publish content We are getting invalidation message where as cache is getting cleared after 4 minutes only.

> 2020-01-24 21:50:38,105 DEBUG CacheChannel - Received event from
>   another VM [CacheEvent eventType=Invalidate
>   regionPath=/com.tridion.storage.ComponentPresentation
>   key=1:30:570825:460484]
>
> 2020-01-24 21:54:57,214 DEBUG LRUPolicy - Removing node with key
>   1:30:570825:541902

Unable to find the reason for delay. Can you please help.

Comment: Could it be an issue with a network the latency between the Deployer and ActiveMQ, and then ActiveMQ to content service, double-check?

Comment: Can you look in the deployer's cd_core log? There should be messages about sending events to ActiveMQ in there. You could compare the timestamps.

Comment: Verified Deployer's cd_core logs, Cache Invalidation message has been sent immediately, once content published and even Application receiving  Cache Invalidation message immediately, But to get LRUPolicy called its taking 4 minutes.